# Slow response in insert via C# code

Tags: sql-server, .net-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

My software takes a lot of time to add about 2500 rows into a SQL Server 2008 R2 but I have the same issue on 2005.

I am not using transaction, I don't need too much performance, but I don't understand why the time execution is not constant.

Every insert creates new `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`, pooling set true.

Usually the insert takes 3/4 ms... but every 3/4 insert I got a 200ms of execution time!!!

This means that I need more the 200ms to insert 3 or 4 row.

I am working via network from another pc using sql native client, running the same application on local machine it work a lot faster.

Comment: Why is every insert creating new SqlConnection? Reuse the connection. That alone should give you a decent performance boost.

Comment: there is no difference reuse the connection or creating new sqlconnection with Pooling enabled... tried both same result.

Comment: It sounds like it could be related to the `Auto Close` or `Auto Update Statistics` options, or to automatic file growth. Have you tried using the [`SqlBulkCopy` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to insert the data?

Comment: i'll check the properties Tomorrow... if i don't find a solution i will replace it with command transaction or bulkcopy. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bulk inserts

I'm not sure if you're using MS Enterprise Libraries, you could do something like:

```
using (DbConnection connection = db.CreateConnection())
{
     connection.Open();
     DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

     try
     {

          // insert a bunch of rows here. You could try to insert all 2500, but that leaves your transaction open for the whole duration. Or you could break it into 100 inserts. Test it out to see what suits your application better.
          transaction.Commit();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          transaction.Rollback();
     }
     connection.Close();
}
```

The gist is that if you use the same transaction for a bunch of inserts instead of one transaction per insert, you'll be writing less to the logs, thus making it faster.